# How to Insert LinkList into Orient Db using batch command?

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to insert some values to a table using Batch URL in orient db.

this is json string.

```
{"transaction":true,"operations":[{"type":"script","language":"javascript","script":"var result2= db.command(\"insert into ChatConversation set ChatID = 19,Messages = 28:119\")"}]}
```

But this gives an error.

error:

```
{
  "errors": [{
      "code": 500,
      "reason": 500,
      "content": "com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OValidationException: The field 'ChatConversation.Messages' has been declared as LINKLIST but an incompatible type is used. Value: [#28:119]"
      }
  ]
}
```

please advice me to solve this.
Thank in advance

Comment: Can you please provide the output of ```SELECT FROM #28:119```

Comment: `{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@rid": "#28:119",
            "@version": 2,
            "@class": "Message",
            "ChatID": 1,
            "Sender": "#12:0",
            "Reciever": "#12:1",
            "Message": "hey+v+1.00",
            "ChatTime": "2016-07-07 05:56:47",
            "isView": "1",
            "@fieldTypes": "Sender=x,Reciever=x,ChatTime=t"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 0.355 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}`



output of `SELECT FROM #28:119 `

Comment: It doesn't seems to be a ```LINKLIST```

Comment: The json string mentioned in very first has Property called `Messages`. I am adding other tables `rid`'s to that `Messages` Field. The last result is from the table where the `rid`'s is getting. in this case #28:119 is the` rid` that i want to insert to linklist.

Answer (score 1):

To insert data into LinkList use this syntax:

`insert into ChatConversation(Messages) values ([#28:119,#ANOTHER_RID,#THIRD_RID])`

Comment: Using Batch URL(REST API) i think it will raise an error we use "[ ]" in json string..